# "shelling" a sphere

Tags: animation, keyframes

I am trying to animate a growing shell on a sphere in an animation. It basically needs to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

with a linear change over time. But I dont know how to add a keyframe for a property such as this. I just rescaled the mesh to make the black slice bigger, but when I do this it changes for the whole animation. I'm quite new to blender so probably I'm missing something really easy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add more details on how you want the effect to look?

Comment: I want the black faces to become thicker over time, starting from the first photo, ending with the second one.

Comment: Which "property" are you talking about? You need to keyframe whatever you are changing to make that happen (before and after). It could also be done with shape keys (then animated with keyframes), probably, but too little detail on how you did that above.

Comment: There should be a ring of vertices that begint toward the edge of the sphere that gradually goes more to the core. So I am working in edit mode and i cannot seem to ondertussen keyframes there

Comment: So you should use shape keys..

Comment: @Ivo feel free to add an answer yourself, explaining a bit what you did, to future readers' benefit.